# How can I keep this simple bash prompt from line breaking in Git Bash?

Tags: windows, bash, git-bash

I have the following bash prompt defined:

```
PS1='$(printf "%*s\r%s" $(( COLUMNS+10 )) "\[\033[00;90m\]\w" "\[\033[00;00m\]> ")'
```

Which displays in a single line inside macOS' Unix shell:

```
> _                          ~/Desktop
```

But when transferred to my .bashrc on Windows for Git Bash, it displays my "prompt" one line below the path, rather than keeping it on one line:

```
                             ~/Desktop
> _
```

This has nothing to do with resizing the window dimensions, the offset of 10 is correct.  But I cannot seem to have the right justified path displaying on the same line as my > prompt, as it does on macOS and Linux.

Might this be some symptom of using the Git Bash shell?  Or is there something I could try to remedy this?

Comment: Does changing `\r` to `\r\n` fix it?

Comment: No unfortunately, there's no visual difference after reloading with that change.